# now() or date('y-m-d') doesn't work when trying to query using php and sql to a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, time

I'm trying to check to see if one date (in my database) is larger (later) then the current date. I've looked on other questions for a solution but none of them seem to work.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_details, rental_details WHERE customer_details.customer_ID = rental_details.customer_ID AND rental_details.date_return >= date('y-m-d')";
```

I've also tried

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_details, rental_details WHERE customer_details.customer_ID = rental_details.customer_ID AND rental_details.date_return >= now()";
```

I've tried every combination of parentheses and brackets with these two, nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?
This is not a duplicate question, I've looked all over stack overflow.

Comment: What’s the table structure/column type? What does “not work” mean exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SELECT * FROM customer_details inner join rental_details 
on customer_details.customer_ID = rental_details.customer_ID  
where rental_details.date_return >= date(now())
```

Comment: Curdate() seems like (fractionally) less typing

Comment: I already tried Curdate(), didn't work. date(now()) works so yay